# VS 2010: Publish dialog settings not saving for web app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, publish

I have an issue that is occurring with one specific solution.  Everything works fine for the others.

When you right-click on a web project to publish, it asks you to specify information before you publish.  I choose File System, tell it to delete all files, and specify a path.  After I publish and shut down the solution, I will open it later again to do another publish.  After I do this, I have to set everything back up.  This means browsing to the folder every time to point to the publish location.

No other projects in any other solutions have this issue.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to check is that the local storage file where the web publish settings go isn't read-only. For example, make sure you haven't accidentally checked it in to source control.

The publishing profiles file will be in the same location as the project file, named $(ProjectName).Publish.xml.

Comment: You're right! I thought checking if the .suo file was read-only would help, but I didn't even know about that XML file. It was indeed read-only. I changed it and now my publish settings are saving. Thx.  Will mark yours as best answer as soon as I am allowed

Comment: What if there is no $(ProjectName).Publish.xml file? Are the publish profiles maybe stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I got here. After I found publish.xml file no where, I did following steps and it worked:

- Right Click on Project in Solution Explorer.
- Select "Build Deployment Package"

You're done.
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

The publishing profiles file will be in the same location as the project file, named `$(ProjectName).Publish.xml`.

just delete `$(ProjectName).Publish.xml` file in project folder.